# Can I schedule multiple versions of a page I am publishing?

Tags: publishing-page, schedule

When we need to make changes to our Intranet homepage we use the scheduling feature to allow us to make our changes visible to users at a set time.(We normally change the page at a time when very few users will be logged in)

Is it possible for us to set up multiple versions of the page and through scheduling have them go live in order or can we only have a single new version scheduled at once?

For example:

Version1: Live

Version2: Publish 14:00 09 Feb 2016

Version3: Publish 14:45 09 Feb 2016

Version4: Publish 00:01 10 Feb 2016

Comment: Without custom code, I don't see any way to achieve this OOTB.